# Faster way than "subs" function for Symbolic substitution

Tags: matlab

I want to ask if there is a faster way for Symbolic substitution than using the Function `subs`

It took with me for substituting 0.12 second and I am running that in a for loop because I have every time new variables to use and the for loop is running around 300000. So is there faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Answer

using matlabFunction. It takes a longer time to generate a file but,after that things will be faster.
And as long as I want to substitute in the for loop so this one is incredibly faster. It took 0.0008 sec